# Jumps, remove one element in a sum

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I'm trying to do my objective function with a double sum like this :

```
@objective(pp, Min, sum(data[i,j]*x[i,j] for i=1:cust_dep, j=1:cust_dep, i!=j));
```

And I want to sum and make sure that i and j is not equal. But I got an error here and I did'nt manage to find the correct answer with Google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#objective-and-constraints :

```
sum(expression for i = I1, j = I2 if cond)
```